# Can products of Claisen Condensation undergo the reaction again?

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

I have a reaction of ethyl acetoacetate with 1-bromopentane in ethanol and sodium ethoxide. I understand that the main product is formed by SN2 mechanism between ethyl acetoacetate and 1-bromopentane, but can the acetoacetate also undergo Claisen Condensation in this case? It has two alpha-hydrogens, so it should be technically possible. Or is it due to stereochemistry that the Claisen Condensation can´t appear with ethyl acetoacetate?

Comment: Going to depend on the reaction conditions - how much pentyl bromide and ethoxide was added. 2 eq of ethoxide and 1 eq of bromide gives you the very stable anion of the pentyl acetoacetate, a 2nd eq of pentyl bromide gives you the neutral di-pentyl acetoacetate. More ethoxide then creates the possibility of Claisen.

Comment: It's not stereochemistry, but steric hindrance that hampers disubstitution. It could still happen to some extent, though, if you're not careful.